# Angular missing id attribute in DOM despite displaying "ng-reflect-id"

Tags: html, angular, dom

What could cause Angular to not add the `id` attribute to my component in the DOM.

TS:

```
export class InputComponent extends BaseComponent {
    @Input() public id: string = '';
    ...
}
```

HTML :

```
    <lib-input
        id="{{ vo.id }}-username"
        label="Username"
        i18n-label
        [control]="vo.loginForm.username"
        [autofocus]="true"
    ></lib-input>
```

DOM :

```
<lib-input label="Username" 
   ng-reflect-label="Username" 
   ng-reflect-id="lib-ui-login-username" 
   ng-reflect-control="[object Object]" 
   ng-reflect-autofocus="true">
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ahe8qy)

Comment: Try [attr.id]="vo.id + ‘-username’"

Comment: Yeah that would just duplicate the information, not a great alternative.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean about duplication? Anyway, this is the angular way to set an attribute on a DOM node 

Comment: having `id` (for the input) + `attr.id` (for the attribute)

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding you.. but attr.id is rendered as id in the DOM.. so it would be strange if you need both?

Comment: Yeah but the id in not passed as input in the component, I want both behaviours.

Comment: Right, gotcha! ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string interpolation is at fault. Without `{{...}}` the `id` appears as expected in the DOM.

I'm very disappointed that Angular doesn't handle it.

Edit: Actually `HostBinding` is a nice workaround.

```
export class MyInput {
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('attr.id')
  id: string;
}
```

Comment: That kinda does exactly as my first comment.. with more code .